# Resolving pmd error "Avoid assignments in operands..."

Tags: pmd, ternary

```
$scope.nodataCheck("W",$scope.groups) && $scope.nodataCheck("b",$scope.groups) ?$scope.noWatsonData=true:$scope.noWatsonData=false;
```

I am getting a pmd error saying,"Avoid assignments in operands; this can make code more complicated and harder to read.  This is sometime
indicative of the bug where the assignment operator '=' was used instead of the equality operator '=='."

How could I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning `true` or `false` to `$scope.noWatsonData`. This is buried at the end of the line, so it's hard to see and easy to overlook. You could move the assignment to the beginning - so that it is clear, that this line determines the new value for `$scope.noWatsonData`:

```
$scope.noWatsonData = $scope.nodataCheck("W",$scope.groups)
    && $scope.nodataCheck("b",$scope.groups) 
    ? true
    : false;
```

As we are now merely assigning true/false according to the condition, we could assign just it without the ternary operator and make it even shorter:

```
$scope.noWatsonData = $scope.nodataCheck("W",$scope.groups)
    && $scope.nodataCheck("b",$scope.groups);
```

For reference, this is about the PMD JavaScript Rule [AssignmentInOperand](http://pmd.github.io/pmd-5.5.1/pmd-javascript/rules/ecmascript/basic.html#AssignmentInOperand)